# Complex attribute that holds another complex attribute

Tags: scim

As per the [RFC7643 section 2.3.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643#section-2.3.8)

> A complex attribute MUST NOT contain sub-attributes that have sub-attributes (i.e., that are complex).

But when I read the Schema definition in the same [RFC section 8.7.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643#section-8.7.2) line 88, I noted the `urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:core:2.0:Schema` description is:

```
  {
    ...
    "attributes" : [
      ...
      {
        "name" : "attributes",
        "type" : "complex",
        "multiValued" : true,
        "description" : "A complex attribute that includes the
          attributes of a schema.",
        "required" : true,
        "mutability" : "readOnly",
        "returned" : "default",
        "subAttributes" : [
          ...
          {
            "name" : "subAttributes",
            "type" : "complex",
            "multiValued" : true,
            "description" : "Used to define the sub-attributes of a
              complex attribute.",
            "required" : false,
            "mutability" : "readOnly",
            "returned" : "default",
            "subAttributes" : [
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all schema definitions, Complex Attributes may contain another Complex Attribute.
In the [RFC7643 section 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7643#section-7) we can read

> Unlike other core resources, the "Schema" resource MAY contain a
> complex object within a sub-attribute, and all attributes are
> REQUIRED unless otherwise specified.